# Magento 2 : Styles not reflected after installation

Tags: magento2, javascript, css

After installation, the Magento 2, css and js files are not loaded.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: may be you deleted .htaccess from pub forlder or apache url rewrite module not enabled

Comment: apache url rewrite is enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flush cache

Delete var/* and pub/static/*

Use php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Am tried the above mentioned things. but there is no change

Comment: Can you attached a scren from console log?

Comment: console log added for your reference

Comment: In DB, table:
core_config_data
find path "dev/static/sign" and update value to "0";
After that repeate steps, which I wrote above.

Comment: yes. its working fine now.

Comment: can you please share the meaning of **dev/static/sign**

Answer (score 0):

Remove all files from `pub/static` except **.htaccess**

Go to `app/etc/di.xml` and replace from

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
```

to

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

=> Run Following Commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile


php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento cache:flush

chmod -R 777 *
```

Comment: No changes occurred